# dd-wrt update linux BIND A record command for DDNS

Tags: dns, bind

I currently have a DD-wrt router setup using its built in Dynamic Domain Name System (DDNS) which updates a DNS entry with DDNS provider.

I dont want to use third party providers, just my own

What command can I use that will communicate to my Linux Bind DNS to update a record a hostname/domain to resolve to the WAN ip address of the DDWRT router?

In Bind (linux) for my domain zone i allow updates from the lan IP of the DDWRT router
[image]

thank you in advance i hope this is useful for others

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [DD-WRT documentation](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Dynamic_DNS), the "Custom" DDNS service option of DD-WRT is HTTP-based.

BIND's DDNS is an extension of the actual DNS protocol (RFC 2136), so it has nothing to do with HTTP as such. So unfortunately, these two configurations talk about two different protocols, even though the name is the same.

To use DD-WRT's DDNS functionality with BIND, you would need to set up an authenticated HTTP service that will receive DD-WRT's DDNS request and then use `nsupdate` or similar utility to pass the received information to BIND using the RFC 2136 protocol.

If someone knows of an existing webserver application or script like that, feel free to edit this answer or write your own.

Comment: The script could be this one: https://ente.limmat.ch/ftp/pub/software/bash/ddnsupdate/

Comment: @AdrianZaugg That script seems to be intended for regular Debian/Devuan for sending RFC 2136-style updates directly. It would be a good starting point for writing a DD-WRT script as mentioned in Antioch Technologies's answer, but it cannot be placed into a web server to turn HTTP-style DDNS requests into RFC 2136-style requests.

Comment: Sorry, I understood it wrong. You may use my other script for this: https://ente.limmat.ch/ftp/pub/software/bash/ddnsupdate_web/ It is not documented and there are missing checks though.

Comment: @AdrianZaugg Hey, that looks useful for me too! Please write that as an Answer and you'll get my upvote.

Comment: I've just uploaded a slightly better version, that is able to also delete instead of update registered addresses. Some checks now really work... However: I could only test using a freedombox and a fritzbox. For DD-WRT I don't see how to pass the key algo, which must be set to keyalgo=hmac-sha512 (this is fixed for now). Can you find this out? I will then write my own answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

another possible answer lies in a bind server configured for rfc 2136 updates, a jffs partition on your dd-wrt router with entware and its bind-client package installed. write yourself a script to detect wan ip change and perform the ensuing nsupdate, then just cronjob it to run as oft as you like.